# Replace String by python

Tags: python, replace

i have list

> http://lincoln.com/picture/2453345/flower.jpg
>   http://lincoln.com/picture/2354345/flower1.jpg

replace into:

> http://lincoln.com/picture/4453345/flower.jpg
>   http://lincoln.com/picture/4354345/flower1.jpg

i tried:

```
f=open('fileinput','r')
f.replace('2453345/flower.jpg','4453345/flower.jpg')
```

but i have more line.i do it spend a lot time :(
plz show me how to replace line. THanks

Comment: Where do the numbers come from? It's difficult to automate if each substitution is arbitrary...

Answer (score 2):

### Replacing part of the string using regular expressions

See the following solution:

```
import re
regexp_test = re.compile('\/\d')
result = regexp_test.sub(lambda x: '/'+str(int(x.group()[1])+2), file_content)
```

**It will increment each digit after slash ("`/`") by `2`**, so "`/2`" will be replaced with "`/4`" and so on...

The result will give you:

```
>>> print result
http://lincoln.com/picture/4453345/flower.jpg
http://lincoln.com/picture/4354345/flower1.jpg
```

if `file_content` is defined as below:

```
>>> file_content = '''http://lincoln.com/picture/2453345/flower.jpg
http://lincoln.com/picture/2354345/flower1.jpg'''
```

### Using content of the file as a string

As @jsalonen correctly noticed, there is another problem with your script: it uses file directly as it would be a string. You should first **read its contents:**

```
file_content = open('fileinput','r').read()
```

and then work on `file_content` variable, which is string and contains the whole content of the file you have read.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that when you run your f.replace you get `AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'replace'` since - well - replace is a string method, but f is a file object.

One way to do the replacing is to first read the whole content of the file into a string, then run the string and rewrite the modified string back to the file:

```
f=open('fileinput', 'r')
data=f.read()
f.close()
f.open('fileoutput', 'w')
f.write( data.replace('2453345/flower.jpg','4453345/flower.jpg') )
f.close()
```

If you want perform replaces per-line, simply split the the data into lines with `split` and iterate over it:

```
for line in data.split('\n'):
   f.write( line.replace('xxx/flower.jpg', 'yyy/flower.jpg') )
```

Comment: Yes you can. For instance just add several consecutive replace commands such as: f.write( data.replace('2453345/flower.jpg','4453345/flower.jpg').replace('2354345/flower1.jpg', '4354345/flower1.jpg') )

I hope you get the point. And obviously for more replaces a more elegant solution would be required.

Comment: Can you specify how? E.g. what kind of replacement rule you would like to apply?

Comment: i want replace by line.Replace with keyword 'flower.jpg' on the line